# Programming Android Application:

Tags: java, android, database, communication

I would like to create a simple application for communicate between two Android phones.

I would like for the application to connect to the internet, before sending a simple message to a database on its way to the other mobile phone. The use of the internet is to avoid text message costs.

Some advice on where I should look for examples appropriate to my problem would be very kind, also thoughts on the problems I am liable to come across would be a bonus.

This is university coursework, so if we could avoid answers etc I would really appreciate your time.

I have downloaded the Android SDK and the plugin for eclipse and have begun working though examples and studying alot of the sample code from http://developer.android.com

My concern is not the coding but the logic of how my problem can be solved.

Thankyou in advance.

Kind regards

Simon

Comment: are you talking about a socket server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device to Device Communication in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396220/device-to-device-communication-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two slightly different approaches look at how both Twitter and XMPP chat works.  Both provide the ability for one client (mobile or not) to send a message over the internet and be received by another, but both work very differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to begin.  Are you please able to describe more about any approach you're thinking to take?

Of course, it may be beneficial to be familiar with database-backed web apps, and Android web apps.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html